# android horizontal type selector widget

Tags: android

I want to add a small type selector, which will give the user three options (good, so-so and bad).

Quickness and simplicity are the main goals.

Something like this would be great:

[image]

What type of widget should I use? (I'm using android studio)

Comment: down-voters: I tried googling it first but could find the name of such a widget. All I'm asking is for some name or reference, not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't downvote, but the reason might be that you are asking for a iOS-ish pattern, not really present in the android guidelines nor ever promoted by Google.

The common way of achieving what you want in a neat, but framework-accepted way, is using `RadioButton`s inside a horizontal `RadioGroup`. I believe there's no need to tell you how, as there are dozens of questions here and it is a pretty straightforward task.

If you really want to stick with that pattern, you could use some external library, like [this](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control).